# How can I use mutate() to produce a series of items from an external list that don't appear in a given column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data in the form of ID and food:

```
adf<-data.frame(ID=c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c"),
            foods=c("apple","orange","banana","apple","banana","tomato","pear","pear","onion"))
```

I also have a list of required foods that each ID is being measured for completion against:

```
required_foods<-c("apple","tomato")
```

I am interested in producing a column called "missing_foods" that houses a comma-separated list of any and all foods in the `required_foods` that don't exist in the `foods` column of my data, as grouped by ID.

In the `desired_output` below is an example of what I'm hoping to accomplish.

```
desired_output<-data.frame(ID=c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c"),
                       foods=c("apple","orange","banana","apple","banana","tomato","pear","pear","onion"),
                       missing_foods=c("tomato","tomato","tomato","","","","","apple,tomato","apple,tomato"))
```

My attempts at solving this so far have been fruitless.  Ideally, I'm hoping to a dplyr answer that will have the flexibility to allow for required_food lists of varying lengths.  I will ultimately be making multiple required_... lists and hoping to produce a new column for each one.

My attempts:

```
adf2<-adf%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
 mutate(missing_foods= !(required_foods %in% foods))

adf2<-adf%>%
 group_by(ID)%>%
 mutate(missing_foods= paste(!(required_foods %in% foods),sep=","))

adf2<-adf%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(missing_foods= for (f in 1:length(required_foods)){
                     ifelse(f %in% required_foods,paste0(""),
                            paste0(f,","))
  })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "My attempts at solving this so far have been fruitless." I applaud this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `ID` and use `setdiff` to get `foods` which is not present in `required_foods` and get comma-separated value of it.

```
library(dplyr)

adf %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(missing_foods = toString(setdiff(required_foods, foods)))

#   ID    foods  missing_foods  
#  <fct> <fct>  <chr>          
#1 a     apple  "tomato"       
#2 a     orange "tomato"       
#3 a     banana "tomato"       
#4 b     apple  ""             
#5 b     banana ""             
#6 b     tomato ""             
#7 b     pear   ""             
#8 c     pear   "apple, tomato"
#9 c     onion  "apple, tomato"
```

The same can be done with `data.table` as well

```
library(data.table)
setDT(adf)[, missing_foods := toString(setdiff(required_foods, foods)), ID]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, we are using the `desired_output` data.frame as the 'adf' dataset values are not the same as in the 'desired_output'.  After grouping by 'ID', get the elements from 'required_foods' that are not in 'foods' with `setdiff`, `paste` them together (`str_c`), and replace any `NA` (when all the elements are found) with  blank (`""`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
desired_output %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(newmissing_foods = replace_na(str_c(setdiff(required_foods, 
          foods), collapse=", ")[1], ''))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
#  ID    foods  missing_foods  newmissing_foods
#  <fct> <fct>  <fct>          <chr>           
#1 a     apple  "tomato"       "tomato"        
#2 a     orange "tomato"       "tomato"        
#3 a     banana "tomato"       "tomato"        
#4 b     apple  ""             ""              
#5 b     banana ""             ""              
#6 b     tomato ""             ""              
#7 b     pear   ""             ""              
#8 c     pear   "apple,tomato" "apple, tomato" 
#9 c     onion  "apple,tomato" "apple, tomato"
```

---

In the OP's code, it is just creating a logical vector

```
!(required_foods %in% foods)
```

which should be used to subset the 'required_foods'

```
desired_output %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(newmissing_foods = paste(required_foods[!(required_foods %in% 
             foods)], collapse=", "))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
setDT(desired_output)[, newmissing_foods := paste(required_foods[!(required_foods %in% 
             foods)], collapse=", "), ID]
```

NOTE: `toString` is a wrapper for `paste(., collapse = ", ")`